# List of li elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why my code doesn't work.

```
$("#example").find('LI A').hasClass("sth").each(function(){alert($(this))});
```

Firebug says:

> $("#example").find('LI A').hasClass("sth").each is not a function

The problem in this code is `each`, because if I delete it, it giving me no errors.

I need to pass founded value of "a" element to array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hasClass` function returns boolean not a jQuery object. thus it doesn't have the `each` function.

You probably meant this:

```
$("#example").find('LI A.sth').each(function(){alert($(this))});
```

Or this (which is better):

```
$("#example li a.sth").each(function(){alert($(this))});
```

Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

> .hasClass( className ) **Returns: Boolean**
>
> **Description:** Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski. Because your fiddle uses `MooTools` instead of `jQuery` ... :) And you had problems with the `{,(` [Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBwrG/1/). Next time test your code with `jsLint`. Good Luck!

Comment: And if in "a" is e.g. rel, how to get it? becouse .attr("rel") doesn't works - probably returns boolean. $("#example li a.sth").attr('rel').each(function(){alert($(this))}) - error is not a function

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski. `attr` return a string. What do you want to do?

Comment: i want to get string rel from $("#example li a.sth"). But it shows - error is not a function. `$("#example li a.sth").attr('rel').each(function(){alert($(this))})`

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski. That's because `attr` returns the first the attribute of the first element as a `string`, and not a jQuery object. You can grab the `rel` with `each`.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to grab this? I'm combined with each(function(index, rel){})

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBwrG/2/). Please ask more questions in a new question and not in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your application of hasClass is incorrect. It does not return a jQuery Object, but a boolean, so `.each()` cannot be applied to it.

You have to attach the class to the selector

```
$("#find").click(function (){
    $("#example").find('a.sth').each(function(){
        $("#test").append($(this));
    });
 });
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gBwrG/5/)

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski, It wan't working because you didn't imported jQuery library in the demo and the some brackets were mismatched.